# how many callback groups lifecycle nodes use by default and why?

Tags: ros2, rclcpp

I am checking number of callback groups in my lifecycle node using :

`this->get_node_base_interface()->get_callback_groups().size());`

Before initialising any of my own callback groups this is giving me a value of 3. Why is that? Does lifecycle implementation use three cb groups by default if yes then why?

The second part is if I reset my callback group I am not able to access the lifecycle services for some reason. why could that be?